# How to improve jQuery drop down menu animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I have created a simple jQuery drop down menu using the `slideUp` and `slideDown` functions. It works if the user would slowly hover over each allowing the previous one to finish but that would never happen in reality.

How would I go about improving the code so it would be a smooth transition for each dropdown?

Here is a working fiddle of my dilema: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamchristill/mcXBB/2/) and here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  <a id="item1" class="item" href="">Item 1</a>
  <a id="item2" class="item"  href="">Item 2</a>
</div>

<div id="box1">box1</div>
<div id="box2">box2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    text-align:right;
}

.item{
    color:#fff;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:gray;
}

#box1{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
    display:none;
    float:right;
}

#box2{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
    display:none;
    float:right;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#item1').hover(function(){
   $('#box1').stop().slideDown();
}, function(){
   $('#box1').stop().slideUp();
});

$('#item2').hover(function(){
   $('#box2').stop().slideDown();
}, function(){
   $('#box2').stop().slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifies the speed of the slide effect.
Possible values:

1. milliseconds
2. slow
3. fast

Answer (score 0):

check this awesome way to let you hover only apply to filtered not in animation, this will fix your question i guess .

```
 $('#box1').filter(':not(:animated)').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is using [`promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to waint until animation is ended.

You can check how its work there: http://jsfiddle.net/mcXBB/4/

I also changed your events to more flexible way which allow you to handle more menu positions in easier way:

```
<div id="header">
    <a id="item1" class="item" rel="#box1" href="">Item 1</a>
    <a id="item2" class="item" rel="#box2" href="">Item 2</a>
</div>

<div id="box1" class="boxes" >box1</div>
<div id="box2" class="boxes" >box2</div>

$('#header a')
.mouseenter( function() {
    var boxId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.boxes').promise().done( function() {
        $(boxId).slideDown();
    });

})
.mouseleave(function() {
    var boxId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.boxes').promise().done( function() {
        $(boxId).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the direction I should be going but it still doesnt work on the fiddle, if you hover over both quickly, you will see both drop downs which I can't have.

Comment: Sollution should be Deffered Object: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ Ill try to fix my solution later, because its more complicated.